# Diagramming quests with multiple paths when those paths can fail

Tags: game-design, planning, visualization, quests

I'm having a planning issue with writing quests for my game. Let me give an example:

During one of the steps of a quest, the player is sent to a nightclub to ask some questions. There are several ways the player can approach this:

1. The player can enter the club by waiting in line and then talk to the bartender and ask the questions. These questions can be asked by lying to the bartender or by intimidating him.
2. The player can enter the club through violence and automatically intimidate the bartender.
3. The player can sneak through a backdoor and find the items in the employee room.

This is simple enough to model as a tree:

[image: the same quest as the above, formatted as a tree]

What I'm having issues is when it comes to failure and consequences.

For instance, if the player fails the strenght check when trying to enter the club through violence, they are sent to the back of the line but still have access to all the other paths. If they try to intimidate the bartender and fail, they are forbidden from entering the club through the front-door. And finally the player might fail all of their skill checks, which will lead to a safety net to keep the quest going.

Is there a way to represent this kind of flow graphically? Ideally I'd like to represent every possible path and consequence, hopefully making it easier to visualize if I've really thought about every possible scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for an Activity Diagram (UML) or some similar Flowchart adjacent diagram. For example, I made this with [Mermaid](https://mermaid.live):

[image]